# Uploading Multiple Files with XMLHttpRequest Uploads First File with Different Names

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a page that has the ability to load multiple pdf files on a location for use later in another page.

I am using JavaScript's XmlHttpRequest to enable me to send the necessary files to the location. When I was testing the functionality, I noticed something weird was happening: while the same number of files are uploaded with the correct names, when I open them up they are all the first file I selected to upload.

I am baffled as to why this happens and was wondering if you could help me understand what is going on. That would be greatly appreciated.

```
function runRule(){
  if(!workOrdersUploadCtrlr.files){
    alert("No files have been selected!");
    return;
    }
  var thefile = workOrdersUploadCtrlr.files;
  var uploader = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var file = new FormData();
  for(var i=0; i < thefile.length; i++) { 
    if(workOrdersUploadCtrlr.cancelledFiles.indexOf(i) < 0){
        file.append('file',thefile[i]);
        uploader.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(uploader.readyState === 4 && uploader.status === 200){
                console.log(uploader.responseText);
            }
        }
        uploader.open('POST',"/url",true);
        uploader.send(file);    
    }
  } 
  
}
```

Comment: You've to change the keyname of the files when appending a file. Or alternatively rename the key like `files[]`, and append an array of files to the FormData object.

Comment: @Teemu Like file.append("file1", theFile[i]) or file.append("file[]", theFile[i])? I tried the latter and it didn't work

Comment: No, you need an array of files, which you can append to FormData object. That way you don't use the loop at all. If you're sticking with the loop, you change the keys, `file.append("file" + i, theFile[i]);`. Also pull everything else out of the loop, and send the request only once.

Comment: I tried that method but it still happens